# MMDrawerController configure left menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mmdrawercontroller

My Left menu displace center view. It looks worse than if Left Menu cover center view. 
[explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keLwE.png)
How i can configure it?

Answer (score 0):

//MMDrawerController

```
ViewController * centerViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *centerNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerViewController];
ViewController *leftViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *leftNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftViewController];
_drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerNavigationController leftDrawerViewController:leftNavigationController];
[leftNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[centerNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[_drawerController setMaximumLeftDrawerWidth:300.0];
[_drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIColor * tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:29.0/255.0
                                      green:173.0/255.0
                                       blue:234.0/255.0
                                      alpha:1.0];
[self.window setTintColor:tintColor];
[self.window setRootViewController:_drawerController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: sorry , did not see your explanation;MMDrawerController cannot let the leftDrawer cover the centerView, it is just the iOS style, cover the centre View is the Android style, maybe you can try other UI